# Incompatible pointer Type initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'UITextField *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a problem with my App. Currently, i'm trying to PUSH data to my PHP script. However, when I press on the button, the whole App freeze. Here is my code.

GuestlistViewControler.m File

```
//
//  GuestlistViewControler.m
//  Club La Boom
//
//  Created by Kevin Archambault on 2014-04-21.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Club La Boom. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GuestlistViewControler.h"

@implementation GuestlistViewControler

-(IBAction)addData:(id)sender{

    NSString *name = self.NameText;
    NSString *invite = self.InviteText;
    NSString *email = self.EmailText;
    NSString *phone = self.CellText;
    NSString *date = self.DateText;

    NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&invite=%@&&email=%@&phone=%@&date=%@", name,
                        invite,
                        email,
                        phone,
                        date];

    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.clublaboom.com/guestlist_iphone.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

    NSString *success = @"success";
    [success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)responseString.length);
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)success.length);



    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // Dismiss the viewController upon success

}

@end
```

GuestlistViewControler.h Files

```
//
//  GuestlistViewControler.h
//  Club La Boom
//
//  Created by Kevin Archambault on 2014-04-21.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Club La Boom. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>


@interface GuestlistViewControler :
UITableViewController {
    UITextField *_NameText;
    UITextField *_InviteText;
    UITextField *_EmailText;
    UITextField *_CellText;
    UITextField *_DateText;
    UIButton *_SubmitButton;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewController *GuestlistViewControler;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * NameText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * InviteText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * EmailText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * CellText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * DateText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * SubmitButton;

@end
```

Thanks for Helping

Comment: the error message is very clear to me. it is saying you are using `UITextField *` where it is expecting `NSString *` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
NSString *name = self.NameText;
NSString *invite = self.InviteText;
NSString *email = self.EmailText;
NSString *phone = self.CellText;
NSString *date = self.DateText;
```

to:

```
NSString *name = self.NameText.text;
NSString *invite = self.InviteText.text;
NSString *email = self.EmailText.text;
NSString *phone = self.CellText.text;
NSString *date = self.DateText.text;
```

Comment: And now, do you know if there is a way to change the "Keyboard" for a Date Picker for the self.DateText.text when I click on the UITextField?

Comment: @user3558397 You can change it in the storyboard

Comment: @user3558397 Ask this in another question

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the .text property of your `UITextField` properties

```
NSString *name = self.NameText.text;
NSString *invite = self.InviteText.text;
NSString *email = self.EmailText.text;
NSString *phone = self.CellText.text;
NSString *date = self.DateText.text;
```